# cannot load rms package

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, rms

I'm working with R, I have installed the library 'rms' but I have the follow error:

```
> library(rms)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘colorspace’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Errore: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

What can I do?

Comment: What does `.libPaths()` return? What happens if you do `install.packages("ggplot2")`?

Comment: [1] "C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"        
> and

Comment: install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpULADlE\downloaded_packages
> library(rms)

Comment: Nothing seems out of the ordinary there. Can you install `install.packages("colorspace")`?

Comment: @Therkel: yes, I can install colorspace and when I write library(colorspace) it's ok...there is a problem with ggplot2...

Comment: the installation of ggplot2 is also ok, when I write:
> library(ggplot2)
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/myname/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/plyr/R/plyr.rdb': No such file or directory
Errore: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

Comment: Can you please try `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)`?

Comment: @Therkel:I have unistalled R, then reinstalled it, and now with "install.packages('rms', dependencies=TRUE)" it works!!

Answer (score 0):

If you install from base R and wish to install a package and all its dependencies, you need to use the argument `dependencies = TRUE`. From `?install.packages`:

> "`dependencies = TRUE` ... this installs all the packages needed to run `pkgs`, their examples, tests and vignettes (if the package author specified them correctly).

Hence,

```
install.packages("rms",dependencies = TRUE)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The answer offered so far (without any upvotes so far) is useful, but incomplete. It is sometimes sufficient to execute `install.packages()` with `dependencies = TRUE`, but if the missing package is a dependency of a dependency, then install.package is not "smart" enough to recognize that fact. The `ggplot2` package is in the "Depends:" line of the `rms` package DESCRIPTION file, but `colorspace` is not. Sometimes the end-user simply needs to read the error message and install the missing dependencies.

In this case, however, it appears that there may have been a version mismatch of packages and R.